# Using cat function on data type list

Tags: r

I have a variable `Items` with such a structure, which is a list:

```
     value
1  item1, item2, item3
2  item2, item4
3  item5
```

then If I run the code `Items[1,]` I get such a result:

```
[1] "item1, item2, item3"
```

I would like to have this `Items`variable as character like following:

```
\nitem1, item2, item3\nitem2, item4\nitem5
```

then I can use `cat` function on this `Items` variable with the type of character

```
s<-cat(Items)
```

But I can not use Cat function on the variable with the data type of list. My question is now How can I convert my list to characters with the above format? then I can use `cat` function on it

Comment: Are you looking for:
 
   ` cat(unlist(Items))`

Comment: Why do you want to use `cat`? That's very unusual and there is probably a better approach available.

Comment: `Items[1,]` lists are one dimensional. I don't get how this will not result in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `unlist` and `paste` with `collapse` argument as "\n"

```
vec <- paste0(unlist(df), collapse = "\n")
vec
#[1] "item1, item2, item3\nitem2, item4\nitem5"
```

Then when you do

```
cat(vec) #you get
#item1, item2, item3
#item2, item4
#item5
```

---

Or actually a simpler approach without `unlist`ing

```
vec <- paste0(df$value, collapse = "\n")
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(value = c("item1, item2, item3",
                          "item2, item4",
                          "item5"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```